# I can't output an integer to a textView

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to input a Miles Per Gallon Integer then simply reprint that number to the user. I have read countless threads and watched multiple videos but I keep getting the same error. I am extremely new to android development so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.frank.trialapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.TextElementListener;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private double num1;
private EditText MilesPerGallon;
private TextView MPG;
Button btnCalculate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    MilesPerGallon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox1);
    btnCalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(MilesPerGallon.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                num1 =    
  Double.parseDouble(MilesPerGallon.getText().toString());
                MPG.setText(Double.toString(num1));
            }
            else MPG.setText("failure");
        }
    });


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
 findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
 Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return super.findViewById(id);
}
```

The problem lies in the MPG.setText(Double.toString(num1)); I just don't know how to fix it...

Error Log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.frank.trialapp, PID: 8293
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.frank.trialapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: where you intialize your MPG `Textview`?

Comment: Your error explains it all, you get a Null Pointer Exception. What's line 42?

Comment: The problem lies in the MPG.setText(Double.toString(num1)); I just don't know how to fix it... that is line 42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Inititalize your `TextView` in `onCreate` like

```
 MPG= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 MPG= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
 MPG.setText("yourStringValue");
  if the value was integer
  MPG.setText(yourintValue+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

First time, "MilesPerGallon.getText()" return null.

Add "if" in your method "onClick"